# Wand install: TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Tags: python, windows, imagemagick, wand

System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16 installed and runs standalone.

pip install wand successful

[1]:import wand  #imports OK

[2]:from wand.image import Image

.
.
.
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

MAGICK_HOME env is set correctly.
I manually added the ImageMagick directories to PATH

Any idea on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not around windows, but I would assume you would do could set `MAGICK_HOME` at the system, user, session, or runtime level.

For runtime, it might be as simple as updating your python script

```py
import os
os.environ["MAGICK_HOME"] = "C:\ImageMagick-X.Y.Z"
from wand.image import Image
```

For a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) session, run the following before executing the python script.

```cmd
setx MAGICK_HOME "C:\ImageMagick-X.Y.Z"
```

> Note: The path should be a absolute system path to the root-directly of your ImageMagick installation.